# Blur Effect with CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, sass

I'm trying to achieve this with cssn (ignore the white selector boxes)

[image]

Basically, I have html similar to the following:

```
<div class="container>
   <div class="card">
      <h1> Blog </h1>
      <p> Quack </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Now my css

```
.container {
   background-image: // the image
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
}

.card {
    height 200px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(213, 231, 230, 0.51);
}
```

Now this css would put a transparent green card on top of the image. However, I don't just want it to be transparent green. I want it to have a "blur" effect.

How do I go about doing that?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function for more options

Comment: The problem with this is that it blurs everything, including text?